# Error with 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'append'

Tags: lstm

```
for i in range(60,1259):
    x_train.append(training_scaled[i-60:i, 0])
    y_train.append(training_scaled[i,0])
x_train,y_train = np.array(x_train),np.array(y_train)
```

Here 1259 are the number of rows and I am doing feature scaling before running the LSTM model

Comment: I am getting error in line 2 of the code. Please advice

Comment: It means what is says: `ndarray` doesn't have method `append`. Check the usage: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.append.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think according to the official documentation, the correct may be as follows:

```
import numpy as np

for i in range(60,1259):
    np.append(x_train,training_scaled[i-60:i, 0])
    np.append(y_train,training_scaled[i,0])
x_train,y_train = np.array(x_train),np.array(y_train)
```

**EDIT:** (in for loop)

```
x_train = np.append(x_train,training_scaled[i-60:i, 0])
y_train = np.append(y_train,training_scaled[i,0])

# np.append just returns a copy which must be saved for further changes
```

Because the arguments of `append()` is Arg-1: Array to which new values should be appended and Arg-2: Values/Array to append.

For reference, [click here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.append.html).

Comment: Returns: .. A **copy** of arr with values appended to axis.

Comment: Yes that's what @Devesh Singh asked I guess.

Comment: `np.append(x_train, ...)` doesn't modify `x_train`, it returns a modified copy, which you ignore.

Comment: So I should edit my answer as like assigning the append value to x_train again , right ?